# Inserting a value on a specific position in an arrayList

Tags: c, arraylist, data-structures, realloc, memmove

So I am trying to add a specific value to the arraylist.The program works but when I check if the value was added i get the same number everytime.

```
void arrayListInsert(struct ArrayList * list, unsigned index, short value){
    if(index > list->size){
        printf("Index bigger than size ");
        return;
    }
    if(list->size == list->capacity){
        short *array=(short *)realloc(list->array,2*sizeof(list->capacity));
        list->capacity = list->capacity * 2;
        memmove(&array[index],&list->array[list->size-1],sizeof(short *));
        array[index]=value;
        list->array=array;
        list->size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not cast the return value of `malloc()` and `void *` in general to any other pointer type. Also, ALWAYS verify `malloc()`'s return value against `NULL`.

Comment: Why are you doing `sizeof(list->capacity)`?  You need to use something like `list->capacity * sizeof(short)`.  As it stands, `2*sizeof(list->capacity)` is a constant expression.  It makes no sense and it doesn't work.